# How to map in Morphia (MongoDB) field that is an arbitrarily nested document?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I tried this:

```
@Entity
public class Test {

    @Id
    public ObjectId id;
    public Date createdAt;
    public Document data;

}
```

And inserting of such entity works fine:

```
Test t = new Test();
        t.createdAt = new Date();
        t.data = new Document("qwe", 12).append("wer", asList("123", "345", "dsf"));
        datastore.save(t);
```

But there are two problems:

1) On the start of program there is a warm message:

```
06:33:47 [main] WARN  org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.validation.MappingValidator - MapKeyDifferentFromString complained about test.Test.data : Maps cannot be keyed by Object (Map<Object,?>); Use a parametrized type that is supported (Map<String/Enum/Long/ObjectId/..., ?>)
```

2) I can not get back such entity `datastore.createQuery(Test.class).asList())` produce error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.Document cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createList(DefaultCreator.java:131)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.IterableConverter.createNewCollection(IterableConverter.java:122)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.IterableConverter.decode(IterableConverter.java:32)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.Converters.decode(Converters.java:85)
```

How do you keep an arbitrarily nested document in your Morphia entities?

Comment: can you kindly post the complete class related. I am interested in seeing the application of datastore.createQuery(Test.class).asList())